# How can I plot in log-linear scale in R with log base 10 in the y axis and base plot()t?

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot the following:

```
ensemble <- replicate(10, cumprod(c(1, sample(c(0.6,1.5), 10, replace=T))))
matplot(ensemble, type="l", lwd=2, col=1:10, lty=1, log='y')
```

in basic R plot() - not ggplot or ggplot2 but with log base 10, so that, for instance, the y-axis read, 10^0, 10^1, 10^2.

I could leave the y axis unplotted, and then add it manually, but I wonder if I can somewhat modify the `log = 'y'` option, for example.

Comment: So the issue is just the labels on the y-axis? The plot is OK otherwise?

Comment: @neilfws No, I would need to use `log10(ensemble)` before plotting, which I was hoping it could be done in one swoop, as when plotting in base 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I liked what your original code was producing, but with some minor adjustments you can get `10^-1` and similar tick labels:

```
ytick <- 10^(-2:2)
yticklabs <- paste0("10^",-2:2)
ensemble <- replicate(10, cumprod(c(1, sample(c(0.6,1.5), 10, replace=T))))
matplot(ensemble, type="l", lwd=2, col=1:10, lty=1, log='y', 
        ylim=c(min(ytick),max(ytick)), yaxt="n")
axis(side=2, at=ytick, labels = yticklabs)
```

gives something like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```r
set.seed(100)
ensemble <- replicate(10, cumprod(c(1, sample(c(0.6,1.5), 10, replace=T))))
matplot(ensemble, type="l", lwd=2, col=1:10, lty=1, log='y', yaxt="n")
axis( side=2, at=10^c(-1:2) )
```

There is no difference between log2 / log / log10 in this case, its just a matter of where you put the tick marks on the axis.

[image]